# How does Python babel round numbers?

Tags: python, decimal, rounding, currency, python-babel

I'm building a financial website with the [Flask framework](http://flask.pocoo.org/) and I'm currently writing unit tests for it. I'm using the [Babel package](http://babel.pocoo.org/docs/) to [format money amounts](http://babel.pocoo.org/docs/api/numbers/) and I hit upon rather strange rounding behaviour. I would expect rounding to be up in case of a `5`, or to at least be consistent. But look at this:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> from babel.numbers import format_currency
>>> print format_currency(Decimal('.235'), 'EUR', locale='nl_NL')
€ 0,24
>>> print format_currency(Decimal('.245'), 'EUR', locale='nl_NL')
€ 0,24
```

Why is this so, and more importantly; how can I solve this?

ps: I would prefer `.245` to be rounded up to `.25`

[EDIT]

I went looking for [the source](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/babel/blob/master/babel/numbers.py#L254-L282), which links to [some other](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/babel/blob/master/babel/numbers.py#L512-L575) pieces [of code](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/babel/blob/master/babel/numbers.py#L600-L662). But I can't really figure out what's wrong there and why it seems to randomly round up or down. Anybody any idea?

Comment: Sounds like bankers' rounding : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even

Comment: [obligatory warning about doing financial calculations in floating point](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?FloatingPointCurrency).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you follow the code through to `apply` you can see a reference to a `bankersround` procedure, which tells us what we need to know.  Babel is using the bankers round method of rounding, which rounds to the nearest even number on 5.  So, .245 and .235 round to .24 as .24 is the closest even value for each.  Values above and below 5 round normally.